# UIScrollView size to match UITextView size

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextview

I have a `UIScrollView` with a block of text in a `UITextView`. The text could be any amount of words coming from a server.

I want the scroll view to be the correct scroll size to match the size of the `UITextView`.

What is the current practice to do this?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: UITextView has it's own scrolling, why are you placing it over UIScrollView

Comment: I know this, but the client wants one big scrolling view.

Comment: You can create `uilabel` with dynamic height and gave that height to `uiscrollview`.

Answer (score 2):

*UITextView* is an extension of *UIScrollView*. So you can get its content size using ***contentSize*** propery.

Comment: That's very smart Nice

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like below to get the height for your textview

```
CGSize size = [@"Your string" 
           sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT" size:22] 
           constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(500, CGFLOAT_MAX)];

_textView.frame = CGRectMake(x,y, width, size.height);  
_scrollview.frame = CGRectMake(x,y, width, size.height);
```

or there is a littl hack you can use :p
 Use a Label to get the height for your text view.

```
   UILabel *tempLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrmae:_textView.bounds];
   tempLabel.numberOfLines = 0; // Important to do 
   tempLabel.text = @"Your Text";
   [tempLabel sizeToFit]; // This will resize your Label and now you can use it's height to manage your textView.
```

Now use this tempLabel's height

```
tempLabel.frame.size.height
```